# ArcGIS Pro: Changed my coordinate system, but still can't import data according to my local coordinate system

Tags: arcgis-desktop, coordinate-system, arcgis-pro

I've changed my coordinate system in the map properties to a local system (Israeli). But the coordinates displayed on screen are still in the default system:

[image]

So when I try to add a point via absolute X,Y. It wont let me add via my local coordinate system

[image]

Likewise, when I try to add a CSV file, it comes up with errors. I assume because the data is in my local coordinate system.

Anyone know how to change this?

Comment: Details please on your local coordinate system.

Comment: Hey, it is the New Israeli Grid (ITM). The X & Y coordinates are usually displayed as two numbers without any decimals, degree or N/E. It looks something like this: 222286, 631556.

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried setting the coordinate system to [EPSG:2039](https://epsg.io/2039)?

Answer (score 0):

if you are using a local coordinate system, you will usually have to use metres as the displayed coordinate unit.

If you have coordinates given in degrees in the csv file it will probably be in the wgs84 system. So just import them in this coordinate system and then do a project to the your local coordinate system